# Confusion to select a row of grid in Extjs

Tags: gridview, extjs, grid

This is a serious problem that I encounter in my application.

I have 3 panels that contain one grid each. following an event I want a specific row is selected.

The problem is that the line is selected but always in the last grid: The Third ..

I give a little bit of my code:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp.('IndicatorsListView').items.getAt (0); 

grid.getView.().select(index).;
```

In this code a line must be selected in the first grid `(getAt (0));`

but it will still be selected in the final grid.

If someone could help me thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code for what you are doing.Did you check that the Ext.getCmp.('IndicatorsListView').items.getAt (0) returning the grid you want?

Comment: Yes, it return out the grid that I want, I can even make an expand I want but it does not work to select the line ... 

when I do: Ext.getCmp ('IndicatorsListView') items.getAt (0) .expand (). it works very well and it opens the grid I want.